# UITableViewController changes UITableView's frame when app enters back into foreground and becomes active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController`, that is embedded in a `UITabBarController` and also managed by a `UINavigationController`.

The only place that I have been able to customize the `UITableViewController's` table view frame is in `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    [self customizeTableViewAppearance];
}
```

Here is the `customizeTableViewAppearance` method:

```
- (void)customizeTableViewAppearance
{
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0);

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568) {

        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 460)];

    } else {

        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 370)];

    }
}
```

This works perfectly when first using the app, but if you go to the device's home screen, and then resume using the app again, none of the usual view methods are called and the table view has been moved. So for whatever reason, even though view methods are not called, `UITableViewController` is changing the custom frame that I have set for it's `UITableView`.

Sure enough, if I move to a different tab, and then revisit the tab again, the view methods are called and the `UITableView's` frame is correct again.

How can I make it so that if the user leaves the app, and then resumes the app again later, that my frame will stay set and not be reset by the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I have to ask, why are you setting the frame differently for different devices?

Comment: @Mike That's just the way I know how to do it. Should I be doing it differently? Please let me know. I want to be following best practices.

Comment: What happens if you remove that method entirely? I've never written such a method before and I've using hundreds of table views.

Comment: The whole point of that method is to correctly size and position the table view so that cells are not hidden. Do you know what I mean? Like, you can still scroll the table view but it'll bounce and some cells are half hidden towards the bottom or top.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? The cells should always start under the navigation bar by default. Chances are you're doing something else to cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear why you are manipulating the frame of your `UITableViewController`'s `tableView`, but in most cases, you shouldn't.

From what you pasted, it seems like are trying to prevent the `tableView` or its content from appearing underneath your navbar, and your tabbar.

Instead of changing the `tableView`'s frame, you should try one of the following things:

- Try setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` when initialising your `UITableViewController`

or:

- Make sure `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES` when initialising your `UITableViewController`

or, if for some reason you need to manage your `tableView`'s `contentInset` manually:

- Make sure `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` when initialising your `UITableViewController`. Now implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as follows

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
  {
      [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
      self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);
  }
  ```

Edit: 
I just saw you're using a Storyboard. You can either set the edgesForExtendedLayout or automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets from within your storyboard, or set them by implementing the `-(void)awakeFromNib;` method.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer because those are all helpful and I will definitely be referncing this later. All I had to do was go into Storyboard, select my UITableViewController, and uncheck the boxes for Extend Edges > Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars and now none of the table view cells are partially hidden by bar elements anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *why* you are doing what you're doing, an easy solution to handle that case would be the following - Add this in your tableView's init method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(customizeTableViewAppearance) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

That way, any time your application becomes active again your tableView will call that method.

Comment: "Add this in your tableView's init method" - I am using a a UITableViewController in a Storyboard, so I don't currently have an init method for my table view in code.

Comment: how about viewDidLoad?

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks anyways for the help though I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this was to override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and place my `customizeTableViewAppearance` method inside of it:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self customizeTableViewAppearance];
}
```

The `UITableView` always has the correct frame now.